# Trying to figure out what kind of input signal this loudspeaker amp circuit needs

Tags: amplifier, analog, reverse-engineering

I'm still trying to figure out how this door intercom module works. It's a 18y old siedle TLM 611-0 module, I figured out the mic part, there the audio signal is modulated onto the current the mic amp draws. But the loudspeaker part baffles me. This is the circuit diagram of the speaker amp I reverse engineered from the PCB. I don't really know how it works. It's quite a strange design and I'm not really good with analog electronics. Help is very much appreciated.

[image: circuit diagram]

Apparently some people can't see the embedded image of the schematic, here is a link to it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5t0z.png

EDIT: Updated the schematic to a conventionally drawn one. Old hand drawn version of the schematic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWECd.jpg

Comment: Post a schematic or other technical documentation -- we can't help you without more information.

Comment: My question included the reverse engineered schematic, don't know why you couldn't see it, here is the link again: https://i.imgur.com/Evuv3Wm.png

Comment: Offtopic: I've misread your name 3 times now.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Your brain is probably in a unbreakable loop after reading the profile. You need to kick yourself and engage your other brain.

Comment: Please redraw this conventionally, with the positive rail at the top and the input on the left and the output on the right. And double check it.

Comment: @EJP Given the use of PNP transistors, it might actually make more sense to put the _negative_ rail on top.

Comment: @EJP done. It's way clearer now.

Comment: I don't see how to find the DC operating point with what's shown.